# Use PHP memcache in yii2

Tags: php, caching, yii2, memcached

In `yii2` I need to use memcache plugin I've installed this also will be shown in phpinfo but I get the following error when running the project:

> Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException - MemCache requires PHP memcache extension to be loaded.

[image]

Cache configuration

```
'cache' => [ 
       'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache', 
       'servers' => [ 
           [ 
               'host' => '127.0.0.1', 
               'port' => 11211, 
               'weight' => 60, 
           ], 
       ], 
]
```

Comment: Show your cache configuration.

Comment: 'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
            'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                    'port' => 11211,
                    'weight' => 60,
                ],
            ],
        ],

Comment: are you using the `Memcache` or `Memcached` ?

Comment: i installed memcached on my os(windows 10)

Comment: @AliMoradi : so uninstall it and install `Memcache`. all works fine

Comment: see attached image on post

Comment: @AliMoradi https://pecl.php.net/package/memcache

Comment: i am trying this for local . my os is windows 10

Comment: Moving cache config from comment to answer. Added image.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have got memcached instead of memcache. Configuration in this case should be:

```
'cache' => [
    'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
    'useMemcached' => true, // <--- here
    'servers' => [
        [
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => 11211,
            'weight' => 60,
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: do it but no diffrence

Comment: Is it used in the console or web application?

Comment: web application

Comment: Can you show the screenshot with phpinfo mentioning this as installed?

Comment: double check if there is uncommented `php_memcache.dll` (or similar) entry in your `php.ini`

Comment: there is in a link on my post